# Java + Vaadin problem with creating buttons

Tags: java, vaadin

This is classic example of using Vaadin

```
@Route("hello")
public class Dupa extends VerticalLayout {
public renderButtons() throws IOException, I2CFactory.UnsupportedBusNumberException {
  

        Button kitchen_button = new Button("Kitchen");
        Button bathrooom_button = new Button("bathroom");

     
        kitchen_button .addClickListener(click -> {
           //some actions...
        });

        add(kitchen_button );
        add(bathrooom_button );
    }
}
```

My problem is to access kitchen_button from outside the class. I tried adding this as static, as field in class. Even tried to create this buttons in other class and returns here as parameters.

This function runs always when somebody open a page. So if you open page ( go to the specific endpoint) on firefox or chrome it will run that method twice. This makes problem too. I tried crazy solution like, after creating this button, adding it on the list, and then running my actions on every element on the list. It is very stupid solution because after each opening new page this buttons are creating.
No success..

I would like from another class use that method

```
public void changeColourButtonToRedOff(Button ob) {
    ob.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY, ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
    ob.removeThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_SUCCESS);
}
```

I tried many things as I said above but it does not work

I tried adding this as static, as field in class. Even tried to create this buttons in other class and returns here as parameters.

Comment: At which moment is the `renderButtons()` method called?

Answer (score 2):

I find it is usually best to declare the Vaadin widgets as member fields on the layout rather than locally.

```java
public class Dupa extends VerticalLayout {

    \\ Member fields 
    public Button kitchen_button ;
    …

    public renderButtons() throws IOException, I2CFactory.UnsupportedBusNumberException {
       this.kitchen_button = new Button( "Kitchen" ) ;
        …
    }
…
}
```

To make that button available everywhere, mark it as `public`. Not that I recommend making your Vaadin widgets available everywhere.

You said:

> My problem is to access kitchen_button from outside the class

**Accessing your Vaadin widgets from across multiple classes may indicate a poor design.** Generally best to have the layout manage its own widgets. Other classes should send messages to the layout rather than directly manipulate the content of the layout.

You said:

> I tried adding this as static

No, definitely do *not* do that. Each of your users must have their own instance of the button. With `static` you would have only one instance throughout the entire JVM, and Vaadin does *not* allow shared state/components.  When attempting to attach to another session, you will get an error.